# How to implement a sequence classification LSTM network in CNTK?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, lstm, cntk

I'm working on implementation of LSTM Neural Network for sequence classification. I want to design a network with the following parameters:

1. **Input :** a sequence of `n` one-hot-vectors.
2. **Network topology :** two-layer LSTM network.
3. **Output:** a probability that a sequence given belong to a class (binary-classification). I want to take into account only last output from second LSTM layer.

I need to implement that in CNTK but I struggle because its documentation is not written really well. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [sequence classification example](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/4080c0a5afb4d80ac16de049f7e9cb234527ae29/Examples/SequenceClassification/SimpleExample/Python/SequenceClassification.py) that follows exactly what you're looking for.

The only difference is that it uses just a single LSTM layer. You can easily change this network to use multiple layers by changing:

```python
LSTM_function = LSTMP_component_with_self_stabilization(
    embedding_function.output, LSTM_dim, cell_dim)[0]
```

to:

```python
num_layers = 2 # for example
encoder_output = embedding_function.output
for i in range(0, num_layers):
    encoder_output = LSTMP_component_with_self_stabilization(encoder_output.output, LSTM_dim, cell_dim)
```

However, you'd be better served by using the new layers library. Then you can simply do this:

```python
encoder_output = Stabilizer()(input_sequence)
for i in range(0, num_layers):
    encoder_output = Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim)) (encoder_output.output)
```

Then, to get your final output that you'd put into a dense output layer, you can first do:

```python
final_output = sequence.last(encoder_output)
```

and then

```python
z = Dense(vocab_dim) (final_output)
```

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/LanguageUnderstanding/ATIS/Python/LanguageUnderstanding.py) you can find a straightforward approach, just add the additional layer like:

```
Sequential([
        Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim), go_backwards=False),
        Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim), go_backwards=False),
        Dense(label_dim, activation=sigmoid)
    ])
```

train it, test it and apply it...

Answer (score 2):

CNTK published a [hands-on tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/4080c0a5afb4d80ac16de049f7e9cb234527ae29/Tutorials/CNTK_202_Language_Understanding.ipynb) for language understanding that has an end to end recipe:

> This hands-on lab shows how to implement a recurrent network to process text, for the [Air Travel Information Services](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC95S26) (ATIS) task of slot tagging (tag individual words to their respective classes, where the classes are provided as labels in the training data set). We will start with a straight-forward embedding of the words followed by a recurrent LSTM. This will then be extended to include neighboring words and run bidirectionally. Lastly, we will turn this system into an intent classifier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with CNTK. But since the question has been left unanswered for so long, I can perhaps suggest some advice to help you with the implementation?
I'm not sure how experienced you are with these architectures; but before moving to CNTK (which seemingly has a less active community), I'd suggest looking at other popular repositories (like Theano, tensor-flow, etc.)

For instance, a similar task in theano is given here: [kyunghyuncho tutorials](https://github.com/kyunghyuncho/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/master/code/lstm.py). Just look for "def lstm_layer" for the definitions.
A torch example can be found in [Karpathy's very popular tutorials](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)

Hope this helps a bit..